# Jenkins deploy uniapp project

Tags: jenkins

use hbuilder How to use the built project JenkinsDeploy and push to the test server

The online tutorials all say that they must be used vue-cliThe built project can only be used Jenkins deploy，The online tutorials all say that they must be used vue-cliThe built project can only be used Jenkins deploy